# How to use FlycoPageIndicator in AndroidFragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

Currently am trying to make an app introduction with Fragments, I successfully created it. Here is the screenshot of the fragment app introduction and I didn't uploaded all the 3 screenshots:

[My app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXACi.png)

First question: How to implement [flycopageIndicator](https://github.com/H07000223/FlycoPageIndicator) in it like this:

[PageIndicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frImc.jpg)

Is there any other easy way to do it?

Second Question: I saw in some app that when I swipe the fragment the next is converted to finish how to do that?
Third Question: I want to blur the image of my app. I know its possible in Java, but how in my code?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private FlycoPageIndicaor mFlycoPageIndicaor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager)
    {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }


}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            tools:context="com.example.vishal.myapplication.MainActivity">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                   android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutAppInfoButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGuest"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

OneFragment.java

```
public class OneFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {


public void OneFragment(){

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_fragment, container, false);
}}
```

one_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/one_fragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.vishal.myapplication.OneFragment">


<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="232dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/image1"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
```

TwoFragment.java and ThreeFragment.java have same code as OneFragment.java

two_fragment.xml and three_fragment.xml have same code as one_fragment.xml with different drawable images

Comment: If you want to offer a repo link to your readers, please obtain that link yourself and add it in as a hyperlink, rather than asking your readers to "google it" for themselves. Your job when asking questions is to make it as easy as possible for readers to help you, and not to give them more work.

Comment: very very sorry for that as you can see that my position is 8 so i cant able to put more than 2 links in the description.github Link:https://github.com/H07000223/FlycoPageIndicator. very sorry fot that and thanks for the help :P

Comment: Ah, fair enough. If you want to put in extra hyperlinks, you can just omit the "http" part, and add `github.com/username/project`, which is enough for readers to find it easily.

Comment: ok! thanks btw please help me if you can becouse am stuck and need help badly in this